# "dotnet projectname.dll $date" in powershell script?

Tags: .net, powershell

I've stored todays date in a $date variable and what I'd like to do is to make the shell script run a .dll file with the $date variable as an argument.
Basically a "dotnet projectname.dll $date"

How would one do this?

I managed to do this with an .exe file by just typing & 'C:$path\projectname.exe' $date

But I just can't seem to find information on how to establish this with the projects .dll file..

Edit:
It ended up being as simple as what I had mentioned myself:
dotnet '$path/$projectname.dll' $date
I thought I had tried it several times, even tried Start-Process and whatnot. But I must've initially written a typo or something which I just couldn't recognize (the error message indicated that it was a matter of not being able to use dotnet).
I'm sorry for this post!

Comment: Have you tried out doing what you wrote? `dotnet projectname.dll' $date`?

Comment: It ended up being as simple as dotnet '$path/$projectname.dll' $date
I thought I had tried it several times, even tried Start-Process and whatnot. But I must've initially written a typo or something which I just couldn't recognize (the error message indicated that it was a matter of not being able to use dotnet).
I'm sorry for this post.